# Site speedy on localhost, slow on server

Tags: mysql, ajax, performance, jquery

Hopefully this question will not be too broad/vague/overarching.

I have developed a site in WordPress that uses a fair amount of custom Ajax to load search results. This is not a question (I believe) specific to WordPress or Ajax (and maybe not even PHP, idk!).

The site runs awesome when developing on my basic HP (8gb ram, i7 processor) running WAMP. I haven't seen a single Ajax call take more than 2-3 seconds.

However, when the site runs on my VPS (Hostgator level 9), it is MUCH slower - the ajax calls take on average 6 seconds to complete, often peaking at 10-12 seconds.

My question is this: **is the slowness factor the fault of my php functions (which include some small to relatively large mysql queries), or the fault of the server?** The only reason I ask is because of the incredibly noticeable difference in load times between the site locally and on the server.

I realize this may be vague; if more information is needed I will gladly provide anything I can (except a case scenario, unfortunately I have an NDA that prohibits me from sharing the site ATM).

More info:

Certain ajax calls are instantaneous ( like those that only pull moderate amounts of information from the db)*are* instantaneous.

The calls that take a couple of seconds are those that pull a large amount of information in from several different tables (remember, I'm working in WordPress, and using the WP_Query class, so the SQL queries and even the db structure are not my own - using the posts/post meta tables), generate HTML from the results, and return it to the JavaScript for appending. The primary search results for this site pull in results based off of location, but then also pull in several other bits of data (images, result metadata, etc.). I cannot feasibly see these types of processes happening instantaneously, though they usually happen at around 1 Mississippi locally. The problem on the server is that the same call that happens instantaneously locally, takes 6-10 seconds start to stop on the server.

The comments and answers I've read so far seem to deal with the assumption/scenario that the SQL queries are sinple queries done on an indexed db. The queries that are done are performed by the WP_Query class, and are (IMHO) not simple queries.

When i say "ajax calls" i don't mean just one part of the process. I mean from when a button is clicked to when the HTML is appended.

The site has no users but me on the server; it is not yet a public site.

Comment: Tip: most browsers nowadays have developer tools that include a "Net" pane or similar where you can see a visual representation of asset load times. (2-3 seconds locally is *very* slow.)

Answer (score 4):

> I haven't seen a single Ajax call take more than 2-3 seconds.

On the dev machine with a single user things like these should be instant. A query response in the **seconds** range is most likely symptom of a design flaw (non-indexed database?).

**EDIT:**

It makes sense to start with the DB. You can use [profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profile.html) like:

```
runQuery ("SET profiling=1");
// do your WordPress stuff here
runQuery ("SHOW PROFILES"); 
runQuery ("SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY n"); // where n loops on the results of SHOW PROFILES
```

And compare the results on the live and the dev server. (Note that `runQuery` is an imaginary function).

**Edit2:**

Also consider running your own queries directly on the DB instead of WP_Query. I'm sure you can come up with something better. Check out the [wpdb object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for further reference.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple possibilities here:

1. As mentioned by 'vbence', concurrent users accessing your website(which you can easily figure-out if google analytics is enabled on your website & check under "Real time" OR simply with the help of raw apache logs).
2. Resource limitation(Specifically memory): There might be the case that your application is taking almost all the available memory. Run the `top command` & check the used & available memory there. If it will start taking swap space then things will start slowing down.
   [image]
3. Mysql tunning(This might be the case with you): Simply profile the php script on the server & check which part of the code is taking time to confirm that it is because of mysql. If that is the case, then you need to optimize mysql settings. Check the following post related to mysql slowness on production:
   [MySQL 10x slower on one server compared to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762406/mysql-10x-slower-on-one-server-compared-to-another)

Answer (score 1):

Running stuff locally means:

- just you.
- no trip 'down the wire'
- a dedicated server - your pc.

Running stuff on a hosted server often means:

- many users (even if just 1 for your actual app)
- many trips up and down the wire to get the pages and assets from the server to you (and your requests to it)
- a shared server with other users.

Avoid using local times to be a standard to compare to.  Rather use your VPS times as the norm and focus on them.  As others noted local times over even a second may be suspect.